# Running Linux commands in Android to communicate via serial

Tags: android, linux, embedded-linux, adb

I'm trying to run a command in Android to send output to a serial port.  If I use adb shell and enter the following:

```
busybox echo -ne 'testMessage' > /dev/ttymxc1
```

I receive 'testMessage' on a terminal connected to the board's serial port.

I then run the following command in an Android app:

```
    try
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("busybox echo -ne 'testMessage' > /dev/ttymxc1");
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, I receive no output and no errors this time.
I've tried running without busybox, simply

```
echo -ne 'testMessage' > /dev/ttymxc1
```

But this results in a null working directory, null environment error.  This does work in adb shell though...

Is there a reason the output from running the command in the app doesn't do the same as running the command in adb shell?  Is there a correct way to get this working?

EDIT: please note I'm running as a root user.  I've also ran the following prior to this command and ensured super user rights have been granted:

```
    try
    {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I've found a work around for my particular case.
Simply treating /dev/ttymxc1 as a file like any other and writing to it sends data via the serial port.  Similarly, you can read the file (I've got my read method running in a FileObserver) which will get you any data sent to the device via the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait the result of your command as long at it is async process. 
In your code the command is in process but you don't wait enough to get any result from it, so you got no error/result.

try this :

```
try
{
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(YOUR COMMAND HERE);
    process.waitFor(); 
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Unfortunately, it didn't change the behaviour of the app.  I have a serial console connected so if the process executes, it should've pick up data on the serial port.